# Google Web App not working using a basic Javascript request

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very basic Google Scripts Web App. It contains a text field, with a button.  When the user presses the button, the text field should be cleared.  But when I deploy the app, nothing happens when the button is pressed. Why isn't it working? Thanks for any advice!

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.paramenter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
}
```

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <button id="btn">Clear the text field!</button>
    <script>
       document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);      
       function doStuff(){
          var uname = document.getElementById)("username").value;
          document.getElementById("username").value = "";
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error here:

```
          var uname = document.getElementById)("username").value;
                                             ^
```

See the stray closing paren? Remove it.

---

For the future: look into how to use devtools: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XScE08hy8

This will allow you to understand much better what's going on with your code.

If you had opened devtools (using F12), you'd seen this error in the console:
[image]

...and clicking the "test.html:13" to the right of the error would have showed you the line too (and even the column, look at the bottom bar):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to troubleshoot my code!  Google Scripts did not seem to provide any debugging tools, I will look into DevTools!

Comment: The error actually didn't happen in the Google Script part (the .gs file) but in page itself which is run in your browser. So, the local browser devtools are needed instead of anything on the Google side in this case.